# Latex - Citação do natbib sem colchetes

Tags: referência, latex

Eu desejo que, em alguns lugares, o comando "\citep{XX}" faça a referência no formato [XX] e em outros apareça apenas XX.
XX é o número da referência (1, 2, 3, ....).

Definição do pacote: \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Olá. Seria importante você fornecer na sua pergunta um Exemplo [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](/help/mcve), para que quem for te ajudar não precise construir algo do zero.

Answer (score 4):

Basta usar o comando `\citealp` ao invés do comando `\cite` (ou do comando `\citep`, que você usa). De fato, o pacote `natbib` oferece inúmeras alternativas (como também o `\citet`, mais útil quando o sistema de referência não é numérico e você deseja mencionar um autor por nome, por exemplo), que você pode consultar na [documentação](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) (veja a seção "*Suppressed parentheses*", por exemplo).

Eis um exemplo mínimo de código que faz o que você solicitou (*já que você não ofereceu um exemplo mínimo, fica a bronca: se o tivesse fornecido, talvez tivesse recebido uma resposta mais cedo*).

### Arquivo de código do texto (teste.tex)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Teste de bibliografia}

\author{Luiz C. Vieira}

\maketitle

Este é um teste de bibliografia para o \textbf{StackOverflow em Português} e, ao mesmo tempo, uma oportunidade de mencionar dois dos mais clássicos personagens de desenhos animados. Primeiramente, tem-se Mickey Mouse, cuja primeira aparição ocorreu no desenho \textit{Steamboat Willie} \cite{Disney28} produzido no final da década de 20. Outro que vale menção é o Pica Pau, cuja primeira aparição ocorreu no desenho \textit{Knock Knock} (vide referência de número \citealp{Lantz40}), já na década de 40.

Recapitulando:

\begin{itemize}
    \item Para citar uma referência normalmente use, por exemplo, \verb+\cite{Disney28}+. Isso resulta em uma referência dessa forma: \cite{Disney28}.
    \item Para citar uma referência diretamente, sem os colchetes, use, por exemplo, \verb+\citealp{Disney28}+. Isso resulta em uma referência dessa forma: \citealp{Disney28}.
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{teste}

\end{document}
```

### Arquivo de código da bibliografia (teste.bib)

```
@misc{Disney28,
author = {Walt Disney},
title = {Steamboat Willie},
date = {18 de Novembro de 1928},
month = {Novembro},
language = {Inglês},
year = {1928},
howpublished = {Columbia Pictures},
type = {curta de animação},
location = {EUA},
}


@misc{Lantz40,
author = {Walter Lantz and Alex Lovy},
title = {Knock Knock},
date = {25 de Novembro de 1940},
language = {Inglês},
howpublished = {Universal Pictures},
type = {curta de animação},
location = {EUA},
month = {Novembro},
year = {1940},
}
```

### Resultado<sup>*</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>*</sup>aqui trata-se apenas de uma imagem; o PDF gerado pela compilação do código faz as citações serem clicáveis devido ao uso do pacote `hyperref`.